# Local maximum implies derivative is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> If $f$ is a differentiable real function in an open set $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f$ has a local maximum at a point $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in E$, show $f'(\textbf{x}) = 0$.

I think it would be nice if I could show that each component is $0$, which I think means showing the partial derivative at each component is $0$, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: To prove that the partial derivatives vanish, what have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: @anomaly I read through my notes to find some property that would allow me to claim that the partial derivatives are $0$, but I can't find any facts to use to prove this claim. So I don't have any techniques at my disposal to apply

Comment: You don't need a specific property; just write down the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @anomaly The definition for partial derivative is $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} (x_0) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f_j(x_0 + he_i) - f_j(x_0)}{h}$ (where $h$ is some real number and $e_i$ is a unit vector). That would mean I have to show that this limit goes to $0$ as $h \to 0$. Or show that $f_j(x_0 + he_i) - f_j(x_0) = 0$, but as far as I can tell from the problem, there's no information about $f_j$.

Comment: What are the $f_j$? The given function is a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @anomaly Oh right, there is only one $f_j$ since the codomain is $\Bbb R$, so it is just $f$. So I guess I want to show that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + he_i) - f(x_0)}{h} = 0$ for all $i$. So we have to show $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + he_i) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_i + h, \cdots, x_n) - f(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_i, \cdots, x_n)}{h} = 0$. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Since $f$ has (by assumption) a local maximum at $x_0$, you know that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $h$ with $0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta$ you have $f(x_0 + he_j) \leqslant f(x_0)$. So for $0 < h < \delta$, you know that $\dfrac{f(x_0 + he_j) - f(x_0)}{h} \leqslant 0$. What can you say about the difference quotient for $-\delta < h < 0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\frac{f(x_0 - he_j) - f(x_0)}{h} \geq 0$ ($\geq$ since we divided by a negative number $h$).

Comment: Good. So what can you deduce about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0)$ when you let $h \to 0$ through positive values, and what when you let $h\to 0$ through negative values?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, wow. I can actually see what's going on now. Your pedagogical skills and ability to break things down into simple concepts is amazing. Thank you; your hand-holding here was very instructive. It is because of teachers like you that I am still doing math at all

Comment: @DanielFischer Also, one small subtlety that concerns me. When $h \to 0$, the denominator of the limit also goes to $0$. Is this an issue, and if so, how is this remedied?

Comment: It's not an issue. We have the assumption that $f$ is differentiable, so the limit of the quotients exists. Then you just note that on the one hand, the limit must be $\leqslant 0$, and on the other, it must be $\geqslant 0$. Together, you have the desired $= 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is differentiable, all of the partial derivatives exist. Look up the same proof in a single variable calculus text and then imitate it-- it will show that each partial derivative is zero, as you suggest.